# Show only some set of pieces with xskak

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, skak

The command `\showonlywhite` which I was using with the `skak` package is no longer working with the `xskak` package.

¿How can I draw just some set of pieces?

Comment: can you show an skak example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I already got it. It's regarding parameters of the command `\chessboard`. I was looking for it in the documentation of the `xskak` package, but i just realized that it was in the documentation of the `chessboard` package. I was looking for the `hideblack` atribute.

Comment: I just added the answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documentated in the chessboard documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5}

\chessboard[hideblack]
\end{document}
```

[image]